# How to output text without using cout/printf in cpp and c?

Tags: c++, c, printf, cout

Part of my cpp code look like this:

```
void Error()
{
string line;
fperror.open("Error.txt");
while ( getline (fperror,line) )
{
  cout << line << endl;
}
fperror.close();

return;
}
```

Its c counterpart is this:

```
void Error()
{
int c;
    fperror= fopen("Error.txt", "r");
c=getc(fperror);
while(c != EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
    c=getc(fperror);
}
fclose(fperror);
return;
}
```

This is my project for my class and our professor told us we weren't allowed to use cout/cin or printf/scanf within the functions. So I was wondering if it is possible to output the contents of the text file without using cout/printf? (We have to use void fun(void)-type of functions)

Comment: `fread` / `fwrite`?  Though if this is a C++ class, it's rather moronic to outlaw iostreams...

Comment: [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`puts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts), [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) to name a few. And your instructor needs to understand *no one* codes like that if they can at-all avoid it. Not for formatted output. If you want *raw* output then hellyas.

Comment: Eh.  Even for raw output, the C stuff is rather ugly compared to something like `std::cout << fperror.rdbuf();`

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly other functions you could call instead, but I suspect you've missed the point. What your instructor probably meant was that your function should not print anything *itself*. Instead, it should *return* something that the *caller* then prints. Part of the purpose of your assignment is probably for you to demonstrate that you understand how the `return` statement works and how to pass and receive function parameters. In that light, the use of *any* function to generate output, not just printf and cout, would be an error. Those two were mentioned because those are probably the only things you've been taught in class, and enumerating all other possibilities could confuse and overwhelm students who worry that they're supposed to know what all those other functions are. Consult with your instructor to confirm.

Comment: Actually, she told us to use the four different types of functions(without using cout/printf _specifically_ in them), and the one I'm having problems with is the function that doesn't return anything and at the same time, doesn't receive anything. To me, who's a beginner at this, I can only think of making the function output something if it can't receive and return anything.

Comment: Now you've contradicted yourself. You've just said you're supposed to use those functions, but in your question, you say you're not allowed to use them. Again, confirm with your instructor exactly what it is you're expected to do. Maybe you're supposed to use a *file*?

Comment: We're supposed to use them (as in the four different types of functions); I said we aren't allowed to use cout/printf within said functions.

Also, that's what I did, I used a file but in c++, it still requires me to use cout(at least that I know of), which is why I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ofstream:

```
std::ofstream ofs("file.txt");
ofs << "text";   // This line outputs "text" to file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display your ***output using [fwrite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite)*** in C/C++

*For Example:*

```
char buffer[] = "hello world"

fwrite (buffer , sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), stdout);
```